# Divide one matrix by the other over dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a database of monthly payments to a platform that have been initialized `orders.engagement = 'M'` or that are already monthly `orders.engagement = 'R'`, (where you can see a MySQL Fiddle later in the question). Currently, about 74% of initiations have been converted to monthly payments. I would like to know what this rate is on a monthly basis because in the last few months I only get 45%:

Then, I want to calculate the SQL that calculates the relationship between:

```
Number of initiations resulting in at least one payment in the following months
                          ---- divided ----
                        Number of initiations
```

I want to do this ratio for each month. But in the following tests, I think that when I do my GROUP BY by month I lose the "at least one payment in the following months".

This is what it did to return the number of initiations that resulted in at least one payment in the following months:

```
SELECT orders_1.date, COUNT(DISTINCT orders_1.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
        FROM `orders` AS orders_1
        INNER JOIN `orders` AS orders_2 ON orders_1.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_2.`gxo_vads_subscription`
        # Donde la transacion a logrado
        WHERE `orders_1`.`status` = 2
            AND `orders_1`.`engagement` = 'R' 
            AND orders_2.`engagement` = 'M'
    GROUP BY YEAR(orders_1.date), MONTH(orders_1.date)
```

It returns:

```
...
25/5/2021, 1:10    2 651
7/6/2021, 1:10     2 443
```

[here is the Fiddle related to an extract of the data base](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed044f1/1/0)

And this is all transactions initialized every mez:

```sql
SELECT orders_3.date, COUNT(DISTINCT orders_3.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization
        FROM `orders` AS orders_3
        -- INNER JOIN `orders` AS orders_4 ON orders_3.`gxo_vads_subscription` = orders_4.`gxo_vads_subscription`
        # Où la transaction a réussi
        WHERE orders_3.`status` = 2
            # qui soit après la campagne de pâques
            AND orders_3.`engagement` = 'M' 
            AND `orders_3`.`gxo_means` = 'CB'
        GROUP BY YEAR(orders_3.date), MONTH(orders_3.date)
```

And it returns:

```
...
1/5/2021, 8:04    86
1/6/2021, 4:54    36
```

[Aqui esta el resultado y el Fiddle relacionado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed044f1/2/0)

There is a problem: the results returned by the `count_initialization/count_first_recurrent` division to the second seem to be too high when compared to the average:

```
...
1/4/2021, 1:10    664,25
11/5/2021, 1:10   662,75
7/6/2021, 1:10    610,75
```

It means that there are 6 times more initiations that resulted in at least one payment than initiations, which is impossible.

Here is the script to obtain the average of `0,74`:

```
SELECT (count_first_recurrent/count_initialization) FROM
    (
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_first_recurrent
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'R'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'CB') as a,
           
        (SELECT count(distinct `orders`.`gxo_vads_subscription`) count_initialization
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `orders`.`engagement` = 'M'
           AND `orders`.`status` = 2 AND `orders`.`gxo_means` = 'CB') AS b
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, a much simpler overall query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN o.engagement = 'R' THEN o.gxo_vads_subscription END) as count_first_recurrent,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN o.engagement = 'M' THEN o.gxo_vads_subscription END) as count_initialization
FROM `orders` o
WHERE o.status = 2 AND o.gxo_means = 'CB';
```

You can do the division but this does the raw counts.

You can easily expand this by month:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.date), MONTH(o.date),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN o.engagement = 'R' THEN o.gxo_vads_subscription END) as count_first_recurrent,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN o.engagement = 'M' THEN o.gxo_vads_subscription END) as count_initialization
FROM `orders` o
WHERE o.status = 2 AND o.gxo_means = 'CB'
GROUP BY YEAR(o.date), MONTH(o.date);
```

This would appear to answer your question but I'm not sure the results are useful.  All initializations are in the same month.

Comment: It's very nice to have simplified my query, thank you! But I am worried: in orders I have two kind of rows:  

- initialization transactions of monthly donations (o.engagement = 'M')
- and the actual transactions of these donations. (o.engagement = 'R')

So with your command, don't I have cases where I have monthly commitments (o.commitment = M) that were started before this month's initializations (o.commitment = M)?